# How to execute a SQL script if a SQL Job step fails

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2014, sql-job

We have got a SQL job that comprises of several steps. Currently, the `On Failure` property is set to `Quit the job reporting failure` which only notifies the relevant parties of the failed step. Is it possible to execute a SQL script if the step fails (for further processing etc.) as well as sending the notification? We are using SSMS 2014.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another step that will be executed each time another step fails.
In this step, simply put a `Script Transact-SQL (T-SQL)` in it.
Then on this new step, weither it fails or not : `Quit the job reporting failure`

Make sure no step falls in this step from success.